# CollapsingToolbarLayout and toolbar action buttons

Tags: java, android, xml

I would appreciate if someone could give me some pointers to solve my latest issue.

I have an activity with a CollapsingToolbarLayout. In an un-collapsed state Im unable to get the buttons to work. I do not know how to fix this issue. I have searched on stackoverflow before posting this, but I did not find any helpful tips.

Im posting here hoping for an answer

Thanks

This is my code!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/app_background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.company.walt.activities.photos.PhotosAAAActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ip_photo_header"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/love_music"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="AAAAAA"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/ssi_txt_40sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="BBBBBBBB"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/ssi_txt_20sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ssi_24dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

PhotosAAAActivity.java

```
public class PhotosAAAActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //region WIDGETS
    private AppBarLayout bAppBarLayout;
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout bCollapsingToolbar;
    private Toolbar bToolbar;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    //endregion

    //region VARS
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private PhotosPagerAdapter mPhotosPagerAdapter;
    SharedPreferencesManager mSharedPreferences;
    //endregion

    /* ******************************************************************************************* */
    //region THE ONCREATE
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //region Load Preferences
        mSharedPreferences = new SharedPreferencesManager(this);
        //endregion

        //region Switching theme style
        if (mSharedPreferences.getNightModeState() == true) {
            setTheme(R.style.NightTheme);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        }
        //endregion

        //region Super onCreate
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos);
        //endregion

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }

        //region Calling Methods
        setUpCollapsingToolbar();
        setUpToolbar();
        setViewPager();
        //endregion
    }
    //endregion

    private void setUpCollapsingToolbar() {

        bCollapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        bCollapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        bAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        bAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {

            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    bCollapsingToolbar.setTitle("Post photos");
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    bCollapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /* ******************************************************************************************* */
    //region Used to create the toolbar on top
    private void setUpToolbar() {
        bToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(bToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    }
    //endregion

    /* ******************************************************************************************* */
    //region Used to create the tab layout
    private void setViewPager() {
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPhotosPagerAdapter = new PhotosPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPhotosPagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
    //endregion

    /* ******************************************************************************************* */
    //region MATERIAL DRAWER
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.photo_category, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:

                finish();
                //Toast.makeText(PhotosAAAActivity.this, "GO BACK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    //endregion

}
```

[image]

UPDATE! - 2018-01-13

I figured out what is cousing the the issue but I still dont know fix this
The problem is that if I remove this code then the tabs won't show up, so it feels as if this ***** with me

The issue

```
//region Used to create the tab layout
    private void setViewPager() {


        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPhotosPagerAdapter = new PhotosPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPhotosPagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }
    //endregion
```

Comment: have you debugged, does the take clickListener ?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

in your activity

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

in your xml

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

 switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
 //for menu you should give ids to that menu items in your menu file 
//R.menu.photo_category and after that if you have 2 menu items
// you have to write listener for every single items for onClick like.
        case R.id.item1:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.item2:
            finish();
            break;
}
 return true
```

}

Comment: Tried this, it is not working. Do u have more tips please

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code, both related to the buttons you're trying to get to work.

First, with the home button (or the up button you need to activate it with actionBar before handling events with it. Add the following:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

inside your `setupToolbar` method. You can now access the button using the code you've written under the `case android.R.id.home:`.

The second button has the same issue. You haven't added any logic to handle the button click. Let's say your button on the right has `id="@+id/more"`. Now to define an action for it, you need to put a case with its id inside switch like,

```
case R.id.more: 
   //The action needed for the button
   break;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Back Button on click listener.